# print all the words after a specific word using python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, python-2.6

Suppose i have a file which have following data:

```
<td class="w"><a href="show.cgi?id=120012" title="[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms">[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms</a></td>'
<td class="w"><a href="show.cgi?id=120012" title="[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60500 ms">[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms</a></td>'
```

In this above string how can i retrive the string after title="[Title] @Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms" for both the lines which is under HTML tag and write retrived string on next line.

I want output like this:

```
<td class="w"><a href="show.cgi?id=120012" title="[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms">[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms</a></td>'
&#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms
<td class="w"><a href="show.cgi?id=120012" title="[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60500 ms">[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms</a></td>'
&#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60500 ms
```

Please help me for the same....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regulare expression. If you can tell that your string of intereset is always anchored between, say, `title="` and the ending `ms` then you can do:

import re  # regulare expressions module
  g = re.compile('title="(.*?ms)').search(line)   # search for your string

Then your string will be available via `g.group(1)`.
You might find it usefule to read about regular expressions in the python documentation, it's a very essential programming tool for every language, especially in scripting.

You might also want to add `regex` tag to your question.

Comment: This is really use full thanks.. But I have another question please see my modified question again in the starting of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library, you can do that quite easily :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
myHTML = '<td class="w"><a href="show.cgi?id=120012" title="[Title] &#64;Blue: Session_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms">[Title] &#64;BlueScreen: RCU_PCPU_TIMEOUT after 60033 ms</a></td>'
html_doc = BeautifulSoup( myHTML )
print html_doc.td.a.string
```

*Beautiful Soup* can be installed using `pip` or `easy_install`, or `apt-get` if you're on a debian-based operating system, as you want :

```
pip install BeautifulSoup
easy_install BeautifulSoup
apt-get install python-beautifulsoup
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method :

```
line = line[(line.index('[Title]')+len('[Title]')):]
line = line[(line.index('[Title]')+len('[Title]')):]
text = line[:line.index('</a></td>')]
print line + '\n' + text
```

Although, a better way to go about this would be using regular expressions as mentioned by CodeChordsman